# Why does selenium.keyPressNative() cause the SeleniumServer instance to bubble to the surface?

Tags: java, macos, selenium, selenium-rc

First, some info that might be useful:
I'm running Selenium RC 1.03 on Mac OS X 10.6.4.
I'm starting the SeleniumServer using the following shell script:

```
cd ~/Selenium/selenium-server-1.0.3/
java -jar selenium-server.jar
```

and calling it from inside an Automator action with the following:

```
~/Selenium/selenium-server-1.0.3/start_selenium.sh&
```

I am trying to use the keyPressNative() method in selenium to send the tab key to the browser using the following line of code:

```
getSeleniumInstance().keyPressNative(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_TAB + "");
```

The getSeleniumInstance() method is a wrapper for instantiating DefaultSelenium.  Now, the problem is that whenever I call the keyPressNative() method inside a test case, my Mac plays the default chime, the running SeleniumServer instance (which is running as a background process) suddenly shows up in the Dock, and my test fails.

I thought it might be a problem with my wrapper method, but every other selenium method I have tried works (check(), click(), type(), isVisible() and etc.).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Would this do it:

getSeleniumInstance().keyPressNative(String.valueOf(KeyEvent.VK_TAB));